Setting Up Twenty CRM on AWS Lightsail
I'm interested in using Twenty CRM and am trying to set it up on an AWS lightSail instance. However, I'm fairly new to self-hosting applications and could use some guidance on the process.
can someone please point me in the right direction for setting up Twenty CRM on AWS lightSail? Any specific resources or guides you recommend would be greatly appreciated.
I tried to communicate with the twentyCRM team but they never response on discord I try to create the issue in their repo but the somehow their AI response is not valid
Twenty gitHub repo
issue i raised isuue
It would be helpful if am able to run the twentyCRM on my AWS lightSail server

Sorry for being so blunt or unspecific. I wish I could give you a very detailed way to do this but I don't have the time. I really struggled with this myself but what worked for me was the following stack on portainer. Take into account that I'm using cloudflare tunnel to reverse proxy a domain hosted on cloudflare to my on premises server. This stack relies on internal DNS resolution, you won't need any of that if you host on any cloud provider that gives you a static IP. However if you do use this stack you will probably need traefik to handle the SSL. You could also skip the SSL config completely and rely on Cloudflare flexible SSL with a proxied domain. pg-admin is not necessary but can be useful for navigating the db.  I couldn't make the gmail sync work nor the S3 storage or the telemetry disabling, but that should improve over the coming months. Just redeploy the stack without deleting the datapaths in between redeployments to preserve your data.

Install Portainer
Create the data paths /root/twenty/local-storage, /root/twenty/docker-data, /root/twenty/db-data and /root/twenty/pg-admin.
Start the stack and monitor the logs, if there were no errors on the server, worker and db, then go ahead, open your twenty server container on the portainer interface, go to console, then execute the custom command yarn, once finished go to console again and execute the custom command yarn database:init:prod.
Try to open the twenty web app. If the UI opens you've succeeded, if it opens a blank page but on inspection of the HTML you see that there is some twenty HTML there it means your frontend url is incorrect, inspect further which one twenty is trying to use using the chrome dev tools and reloading.

It would be fantastic if the twenty team gave us their feedback on this for self-hosting and perhaps add this to the self hosting docs.
version: "3.9"
name: twenty

services:
  change-vol-ownership:
    image: alpine
    user: root
    volumes: #
      - /root/twenty/local-storage:/app/packages/twenty-server/local-storage
      - /root/twenty/docker-data:/app/docker-data
      - /root/twenty/db-data:/app/db-data
      - /root/twenty/pgadmin:/app/pgadmin
    command: >
      sh -c "
      chown -R 1000:1000 /app/packages/twenty-server/local-storage
      && chown -R 1000:1000 /app/docker-data
      && chown -R 1001:1001 /app/db-data
      && chown -R 5050:5050 /app/pgadmin"

  server:
    # execute `yarn database:init:prod` manually when setting up database for the first time.
    ports:
      - "${EXTERNAL_PORT}:${INTERNAL_PORT}"
    image: twentycrm/twenty:${TAG}
    volumes:
      - /root/twenty/local-storage:/app/packages/twenty-server/local-storage
      - /root/twenty/docker-data:/app/docker-data
    env_file:
      - stack.env
    environment:
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://twenty:twenty@${PG_DATABASE_HOST}/default
      PORT: ${INTERNAL_PORT}
      SERVER_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}
      FRONT_BASE_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}
      # SERVER_URL: http://${TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}
      # FRONT_BASE_URL: http://${TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}
      AUTH_GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}/auth/google/redirect
      AUTH_GOOGLE_APIS_CALLBACK_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}/auth/google-apis/get-access-token
      ENABLE_DB_MIGRATIONS: "true"
    # labels:
    #   - "traefik.enable=true"
    #   - "traefik.http.routers.twenty.rule=Host(`${TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}`) || Host(`${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}`)"
    #   - "traefik.http.routers.twenty.entrypoints=web"
    #   - "traefik.http.routers.twenty.service=server-twenty@docker"
    depends_on:
      change-vol-ownership:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:${INTERNAL_PORT}/healthz
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    restart: always

  worker:
    image: twentycrm/twenty:${TAG}
    command: ["yarn", "worker:prod"]
    volumes:
      - /root/twenty/local-storage:/app/packages/twenty-server/local-storage
      - /root/twenty/docker-data:/app/docker-data
    env_file:
      - stack.env
    environment:
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://twenty:twenty@${PG_DATABASE_HOST}/default
      PORT: ${INTERNAL_PORT}
      SERVER_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}
      FRONT_BASE_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}
      # SERVER_URL: http://${TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}
      # FRONT_BASE_URL: http://${TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}
      AUTH_GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}/auth/google/redirect
      AUTH_GOOGLE_APIS_CALLBACK_URL: https://${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN}.${TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN}/auth/google-apis/get-access-token
      ENABLE_DB_MIGRATIONS: "false" # https://github.com/twentyhq/twenty/issues/5880
    depends_on:
      server:
        condition: service_healthy
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always

  db:
    image: twentycrm/twenty-postgres:${TAG}
    volumes:
      - /root/twenty/db-data:/bitnami/postgresql
    env_file:
      - stack.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${PG_PORT}:${PG_PORT}"
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U twenty -d default
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-admin}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
       - /root/twenty/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    restart: unless-stopped

  cloudflared:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:2022.5.1
    container_name: cloudflared
    restart: always
    command:
      - tunnel
      - --no-autoupdate
      - run
      - --token=${CLOUDFLARED_TOKEN}

Use the following env vars in the stack env vars on advanced mode (just copy and paste the dotenv).
TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN=twenty
TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN=localdomain
TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN=twenty
TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
TAG=latest
MESSAGE_QUEUE_TYPE=pg-boss
SIGN_IN_PREFILLED=true
STORAGE_TYPE=local
AUTH_GOOGLE_ENABLED=true
IS_SIGN_UP_DISABLED=true
TELEMETRY_ENABLED=false
MESSAGING_PROVIDER_GMAIL_ENABLED=true
CALENDAR_PROVIDER_GOOGLE_ENABLED=true
EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contact@mydomain.com
EMAIL_FROM_NAME=Customer support mydomain.com
EMAIL_SYSTEM_ADDRESS=contact@mydomain.com
EMAIL_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_SMTP_PORT=465
EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD=myappspecificpass
OPENROUTER_API_KEY=sk-or-v1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STORAGE_S3_REGION=us-east-1
STORAGE_S3_NAME=my-twenty-storage-bucket
STORAGE_S3_ENDPOINT=https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STORAGE_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=GOCxxX-__xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LOGIN_TOKEN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FILE_TOKEN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
INTERNAL_PORT=80
EXTERNAL_PORT=3000
PG_DATABASE_HOST=db:5432
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=myemail@mydomain.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PG_PORT=5432
PGADMIN_PORT=5050
POSTGRES_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CLOUDFLARED_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

In case you go for the on premises + cloudflare tunnel route consider the following cloudflare tunnel config:

Go to the cloudflare zero trust panel, then Networks, then Tunnels, open your pre configured tunnel (you'll have to investigate about this separately).
Go to the public hostnames tab, then Add a public hostname.
Subdomain: the value of $TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN, make sure this subdomain does not have an A or CNAME dns record on it, cloudflare will create it automatically.
Domain: the value of $TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN, your domain hosted on cloudflare for example twenty.mydomain.com
Type: http (unless you configured reverse proxy with ssl on your portainer)
URL: the value of TWENTY_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN and TWENTY_LOCAL_DOMAIN and your local port, for example twenty.localdomain:3001
Open the advanced settings, enable HTTP Host Header, use TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_SUBDOMAIN and TWENTY_CLOUDFLARE_DOMAIN to match your SERVER_URL for example twenty.mydomain.com.

